# Bloquear registro al leerlo

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos MySQL con varias tablas y lo que quiero es bloquear un registro al leerlo para que no sea leído por otro usuario hasta que deje de leerlo o modificarlo.

¿Hay algo en MySQL que me permita hacer eso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si son tablas MyISAM solo se pueden bloquear las tablas con sentencias tipo LOCK and UNLOCK TABLES, lo cual no permite que trabaje más de un usuario a la vez. 
En el caso de las tablas InnoDB hay más posibilidades, puedes verlas aquí

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html

De todos modos, puede tener sentido bloquear un registro mientras se modifica, pero mientras se lee, es decir para un select, no parece muy funcional, supongo que tiene que ver con la lógica del proceso que uses.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Mas bien quiero que no lo vuelvan a leer si alguien lo esta utilizando, por que el que lo lee lo modificara y pasara a otra clasificación y ya no estará disponible en esa vista. y si dos usuarios lo hacen al mismo tiempo ese seria el problema.

Comment: Ya resolvi el problema, al parecer estos  bloqueos son a nivel transaccional, para mantener la integridad de los datos, pero parece que no evita que sea leído un registro que ya fue leído.... Creo que lo mas optimo seria utilizar una bandera, no veo otra forma de evitar que lo vuelvan a leer al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Estupendo. Esa me parece una buena idea Rodrigo, mejor que hacer bloqueos en la base de datos.

Comment: Rodrigo si consideras que está respondida la pregunta marcala como tal para que no aparezca sin respuesta.

Comment: no se como cerrarla.

Comment: Sólo tienes quye hacer click en el check que aparece bajo la respuesta en gris para que pase a verde :)

Comment: gracias ya quedo listo